# Display toast and clear form after submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

This is a simple contact form using `HTML` `CSS` and `JavaScript`. I am not able to get a message after the form submit button is entered. It redirects me to a page that displays the submitted details and I don't want that to happen obviously. I wish to get a toast message after submit button is clicked, and to reset the form. I have added an extra button just to check functionality for toast. I am really stuck on this!!

***Please help!***

[form demo](https://contact-form-trials.netlify.app/)

```js
(function() {
  // get all data in form and return object
  function getFormData(form) {
    var elements = form.elements;
    var honeypot;

    var fields = Object.keys(elements).filter(function(k) {
      if (elements[k].name === "honeypot") {
        honeypot = elements[k].value;
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }).map(function(k) {
      if (elements[k].name !== undefined) {
        return elements[k].name;
        // special case for Edge's html collection
      } else if (elements[k].length > 0) {
        return elements[k].item(0).name;
      }
    }).filter(function(item, pos, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item) == pos && item;
    });

    var formData = {};
    fields.forEach(function(name) {
      var element = elements[name];

      // singular form elements just have one value
      formData[name] = element.value;

      // when our element has multiple items, get their values
      if (element.length) {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
          var item = element.item(i);
          if (item.checked || item.selected) {
            data.push(item.value);
          }
        }
        formData[name] = data.join(', ');
      }
    });

    // add form-specific values into the data
    formData.formDataNameOrder = JSON.stringify(fields);
    formData.formGoogleSheetName = form.dataset.sheet || "responses"; // default sheet name
    formData.formGoogleSendEmail = form.dataset.email || ""; // no email by default

    return {
      data: formData,
      honeypot: honeypot
    };
  }

  function handleFormSubmit(event) { // handles form submit without any jquery
    event.preventDefault(); // we are submitting via xhr below
    var form = event.target;
    var formData = getFormData(form);
    var data = formData.data;

    // If a honeypot field is filled, assume it was done so by a spam bot.
    if (formData.honeypot) {
      return false;
    }

    disableAllButtons(form);
    var url = form.action;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    // xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        form.reset();
        var formElements = form.querySelector(".form-elements")
        if (formElements) {
          formElements.style.display = "none"; // hide form
        }
        var thankYouMessage = form.querySelector(".thankyou_message");
        if (thankYouMessage) {
          thankYouMessage.style.display = "block";
        }
      }
    };
    // url encode form data for sending as post data
    var encoded = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) {
      return encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[k]);
    }).join('&');
    xhr.send(encoded);
  }

  function loaded() {
    // bind to the submit event of our form
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll("form.gform");
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit, false);
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loaded, false);

  function disableAllButtons(form) {
    var buttons = form.querySelectorAll("button");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="content-head is-center">Contact Us!</h2>
<aside>
  <p>
    We would <em>love</em> to hear from you! </p>
  <p>Please use the <b><em>Contact Form</em></b> to send us a message.
  </p>
</aside>

<!-- START HERE -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Style The Contact Form How Ever You Prefer -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<form class="gform pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="POST" data-email="" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxud2vvVuUj0YXOasdO50lQwPJc3FnoTZXdNtgRdaYnl70kKDlRO6nS/exec">
  <!-- change the form action to your script url -->

  <div class="form-elements">
    <fieldset class="pure-group">
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="What your Mom calls you" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="pure-group">
      <label for="message">Message: </label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10" placeholder="Tell us what's on your mind..."></textarea>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="pure-group">
      <label for="email"><em>Your</em> Email Address:</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="" required placeholder="your.name@email.com" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="pure-group">
      <label for="color">Favourite Color: </label>
      <input id="color" name="color" placeholder="green" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="pure-group honeypot-field">
      <label for="honeypot">To help avoid spam, utilize a Honeypot technique with a hidden text field; must be empty to submit the form! Otherwise, we assume the user is a spam bot.</label>
      <input id="honeypot" type="text" name="honeypot" value="" />
    </fieldset>

    <button class="button-success pure-button button-xlarge">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;Send</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Customise the Thankyou Message People See when they submit the form: -->
  <div class="thankyou_message" style="display:none;">
    <h2><em>Thanks</em> for contacting us! We will get back to you soon!</h2>
  </div>

</form>
<div class="toast" id="myToast" data-autohide="false">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <strong class="mr-auto text-primary">Toast Header</strong>
    <small class="text-muted">5 mins ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    Some text inside the toast body
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary show-toast">Show Toast</button>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show-toast").click(function() {
      $("#myToast").toast('show');
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- Submit the Form to Google Using "AJAX" -->
<script data-cfasync="false" src="form-submission-hanler.js"></script>
<!-- END -->
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see where you assign handleFormSubmit() to be called when the form is submitted.

Comment: Okay, I will check that, you mean onsubmit();

Answer (score 0):

You can add event on click of button and use reset() to reset the form values. Add following code in your script section:

```
$('.button-success').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()        //This stops page loading
        $("#myToast").toast('show'); //Show toast
        document.getElementsByName('data-form')[0].reset() //reset field values of the form
    })
```

Add name parameter to your form tag to access it inside this function. (For ex: I have added name as 'data-form')

Comment: I am sorry, where do I add it in my script could you please point that ?

Comment: add this inside ur <script> tag

Comment: Add it inside your <script> tag. Add it in same way as you have added ready function. It is event listener that will be called on click of success button.